# Number of ways of filling a connect four column - Double counting

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

What is the number of valid configurations for a column in a [connect four](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connect_Four) game ? Assume that a win or a loss does not stop the game.

Summing over cases with a given number of pieces in the column, (Assuming a height of 6):-
$$N=1+2^1+2^2+2^3+2^4+2^5+2^6=2^7-1$$

Is there an another counting which can directly lead to the $2^7-1$ expression, like when we prove $\sum_{i}\binom{n}{i}=2^n$ ?

Comment: Looks right to me.

Comment: I know it's right. Read the question carefully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your **second** question, consider this. Add another space to your column; so it has seven spaces. There are $2^7-1$ ways of filling it
completely with red and yellow discs, using at least one red disc. Take
one of these configurations, find the highest red disc, and remove it and
any yellow discs above it.

EDIT MADE:

Using atleast one *red* disk instead of Using atleast one disk

Comment: Brilliant and elegant!